# Java - Variables from JFrame Controls

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I'm relatively new to Java and I'm self-teaching.  Currently I'm trying to develop a Frame which includes a text field and a button.  The button runs a SQL query off my personal DB, and I want the WHERE clause to populate with the text from the text field.  But I'm unable to pass the txtField.getText() value to the class where the SQL statement is built.  Instead of grabbing what's been typed in the field, it only gives me what the field's text is at default.

I'm hoping someone could look at my code (below) and tell me where I'm going wrong.  I have a feeling it's when I create a new Frame1 object in the SQL class, but I can't fathom a way around this.

The code for the frame class:

```
    public Frame1() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        stateCodeVar = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        lblStateCodeVar = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtDestVar = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel2.setText("Enter the state abbreviation:");

        stateCodeVar.setName("txtState"); // NOI18N
        stateCodeVar.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                stateCodeVarFocusLost(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("Search");
        jButton1.setName("btnSearch"); // NOI18N
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblStateCodeVar.setText("jLabel1");
        lblStateCodeVar.setName("lblStateCodeVar"); // NOI18N

        txtDestVar.setText("jTextField1");
        txtDestVar.setName("txtDest"); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 207, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(stateCodeVar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 56, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(149, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(txtDestVar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 154, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(lblStateCodeVar))
                .addGap(63, 63, 63))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                .addComponent(lblStateCodeVar)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(stateCodeVar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 70, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(txtDestVar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(103, 103, 103))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        sqlSearchByState sql1 = new sqlSearchByState();
        try {
        sql1.sqlSearch();
        System.out.println("The query is finished.");
        String code = getStateCode();
        /* System.out.println(code); */
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                        

    private void stateCodeVarFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                       
        txtDestVar.setText(stateCodeVar.getText());
    }                                      

    public String getStateCode(){
    String result = stateCodeVar.getText();
    return result;    
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Frame1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    public javax.swing.JLabel lblStateCodeVar;
    public javax.swing.JTextField stateCodeVar;
    public javax.swing.JTextField txtDestVar;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The code for the SQL class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 *
 * @author Eli Oklesh
 */
public class sqlSearchByState {

    public void sqlSearch() throws SQLException {
    dbCon1 dbc = new dbCon1();

    Frame1 f = new Frame1();

    f.getStateCode();
    String stateCode = f.getStateCode();

    Connection conn1;
        Statement stmt2;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userLocation = '" + stateCode + "'";

        conn1 = dbc.makeConnection();

        try{

        stmt2 = conn1.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt2.executeQuery(query);

        if (rs.next()){
            while (rs.next()){
                int userID = rs.getInt("ID");
                String userFirstName = rs.getString("userFirstName");
                String userLastName= rs.getString("userLastName");
                String userLocation = rs.getString("userLocation");

                System.out.println(userID + "\t" + userFirstName + "\t" + userLastName + "\t" + userLocation);


                }
            System.out.println(query);
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("No records were returned.");
        System.out.println(query);

        }
            }
        catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("There was an error:" + "\t" + e);
            }
        finally {
            if (conn1 != null) {conn1.close();}
            }
        }

}
```

Help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You're creating new instance of your frame within your class that's executing the query, but it is not the frame which is displayed on the screen, so the value you are trying to use is not the one that the user entered.

Instead, you want to pass the value from the frame to the class that's executing the sql...

```
    sql1.sqlSearch(txtDestVar.getText());
```

You will then need to change the `sqlSearch` method...

```
public void sqlSearch(String text) throws SQLException {
```

You'll then need to remove the reference of the frame from the sql class and make use of the `text` parameter instead

Comment: MadProgrammer -

Thanks!  This worked like a charm.  And it helps me understand the methodology being used when dealing with multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could possibly be solved by using a modal JDialog and not a JFrame, and I'll explain why...

- When you display a JFrame it is non-modal, meaning the calling code that creates the JFrame and displays it, does not halt, but rather continues running while the JFrame is being displayed.
- So if you try to extract information immediately from the JFrame after creating it (shoot, I don't see that your code even displays it), then it is extracted before the user has had any opportunity to interact with the JFrame, and likely before the JFrame is even displayed.
- A modal dialog on the other hands halts the calling code until the dialog is no longer visible, and this will give the user the chance to interact with the dialog window.
- then when you extract information from the dialog, it will likely be relevant information that was obtained **after** the user has entered it.

Comment: Hover -

Thanks for this insight.  I can say at the moment it's beyond my scope of java knowledge.  But I'm interested in learning more because as I progress in my learning I'd like to know more about the JDialog solution you suggested.  I'll be sure to look that up.. Thanks!